# Мой сервис при запуске контейнера не может получить config из контейнера spring cloud config

Tags: spring, docker, spring-cloud

Всем добрый день! Я новичек во всем этом деле.

Сделал два простых сервиса по примеру Config Server и Licensing server
При запуске их локально отрабатывают хорошо, и даже если Config Server запущен в контейнере тоже отрабатывает

Но когда запускаю контейнер Licensing server, пишет ошибку получения конфигов из config server

перепробовал кучу советов, и link, и networks общую делать, менял конфиги как мог, но все равно пишет ошибку получения

сам docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_DB: "ostock_dev"


  licensingservice:
    build:
      context: licensin-server
    container_name: licensing-service
    depends_on:
      - configserver
    links:
      - configserver
    # environment:
      # - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
      # - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://configserver:8071
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    restart: always
#    networks:
##      - mynetwork


  configserver:
    build:
      context: configserver
    container_name: configserver
    ports:
      - "8071:8071"
#    networks:
#      - mynetwork

#networks:
#  mynetwork:
```

конфиг приложения

```
spring:
  application:
    name: licensing-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://configserver:8071/
      name: licensing-service
      profile: dev
```

Ошибка которая выходит в терминале:

```
46.57 2023-10-06T13:00:16.879Z  INFO 91 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://configserver:8071/
56.70 2023-10-06T13:00:26.966Z  INFO 91 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Exception on Url - http://configserver:8071/:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://configserver:8071/licensing-service/dev": configserver. Will be trying the next url if available
56.70 2023-10-06T13:00:26.966Z  WARN 91 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://configserver:8071/licensing-service/dev": configserver   
56.70 2023-10-06T13:00:26.979Z  INFO 91 --- [           main] c.o.l.LicensinServerApplicationTests     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
```

В чем может быть ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста